# Issue in fetching client MAC ID using Applet

Tags: java, applet, network-programming

We are trying to fetch the client MAC ID using the Java Applet. The applet is loaded via an HTML page.
The code for the same is as given below:

```
public class mainRun extends Applet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4939998186435587428L;
String macAddr="";
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Start");
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println((new StringBuilder("Current IP address : "+ip.toString())));
        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
        byte mac[] = network.getHardwareAddress();
        System.out.println("mac : "+mac.toString());
        System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++)
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", new Object[] {
                    Byte.valueOf(mac[i]), i >= mac.length - 1 ? "" : "-"
            }));

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        macAddr=String.valueOf(sb);

    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
        macAddr=e.toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        macAddr=e.toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    g.drawString("HELLO: "+macAddr, 100, 100);
}
}
```

However in using the getHardwareAddress() method we are getting null pointer exception.

What could cause this problem?

Also when I run this same class as Java Applet on my local machine I get the desired output. I am facing the issue when the Applet jar is placed on the server and applet is loaded on the client machine.

Comment: For what purpose? There's nothing useful you can do with a MAC address in Java except display it. Are you aware that they can be changed by the user? And that therefore they aren't useful as unique system identifiers?

Comment: Yes I am aware that spoofing is possible. However the client wants that (to fetch the client MAC address) to be done and they don't mind if the address is changed. We just want to fetch that address and compare the same with the one we already have in our records and authorize the user to further use the application from that machine.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`getHardwareAddress` requires NetPermission("getNetworkInformation").
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress()

Therefore a applet jar needs to be signed.